# Can not update or delete in local database : Error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am new to C# and .NET, I am trying to implement CRUD functionality with local database. So I created a `Product` class which contains attributes and and  foreign keys. But I get an error when I launch the application. The methods `Update()` and `Delete()` do not work, but `Add()` method works fine.

Here are my generic methods -

```cs
public class GenericRepository<T> where T : class
{    
    GPContext context;
    IDbSet<T> dbSet;    

    public GenericRepository()
    {
        context = new GPContext();
        dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }    

    public IEnumerable<T> getAll()
    {
        return dbSet.AsEnumerable();                
    }    

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }    

    public void Add(T t)
    {
        dbSet.Add(t);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }    

    public void Update(T t)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(t);
        //on modifie la instance avant la inserer dans la bd
        context.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }    

    public void Delete(T t)
    {
        dbSet.Remove(t);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }    
}
```

and here is how I call them in `Program.cs` -

```cs
GenericRepository<Product> productRepository = new GenericRepository<Product>();
           
Address adresse = new Address() { City = "Paris", StreetAdress = "Escalier 9" };
Category cat1 = new Category() {  Name="cat1"   };

Chemical p1 = new Chemical() { ProductId=26,  DateProd = DateTime.Now , myAdress = adresse, Description = "CHemichal Product",
    Price = 55,Name="PHARMA CHEMICH 1", Quantity = 100 , MyCategory = cat1};
Chemical p2 = new Chemical() {ProductId = 12 , DateProd = DateTime.Now , myAdress = adresse, Description = "CHemichal Update Product",
    Price = 55,Name="PHARMA CHEMICH 1 Update", Quantity = 100 , MyCategory = cat1};
Product p3 = new Product() { ProductId = 11 };

productRepository.Add(p1);
productRepository.Update(p2);
productRepository.Delete(p3);
```

Following error occurs when I launch the application -

> System.InvalidOperationException : 'A referential integrity constraint
> violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Category.CategoryId' on
> one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of
> 'Product.categoryId' on the other end.'

Also I have this error in `Delete` method -

> System.InvalidOperationException : 'The object cannot be deleted
> because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.'

The entity classes are below -

`Product`:

```cs
public class Product : Concept
{
    [Display(Name ="Date de prod")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateProd { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Champ obligatoire")]
    [StringLength(25)]
    [MaxLength(50 , ErrorMessage ="taille max dans la base 50")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    
    [Range(0,int.MaxValue)]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl) ,Display(Name ="Image")]
    public string image { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("categoryId")]
    public  Category MyCategory { get; set; }
    
    public int? categoryId { get; set; }
    
    public List<Provider> Providers { get; set; }

    public override void GetDetails()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Product  Name:, Price   "+ Name + " " + Price);    
    }

    public virtual void GetMyType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Uknown");
    }    
}
```

`Chemical`:

```cs
public class Chemical : Product
{
   // public string City { get; set; }
   
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    
   // public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
   
    public Address myAdress { get; set; }
    
    public override void GetMyType()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("CHEMICAL");
    }
}
```

`Biological`:

```cs
public class Biological : Product
{
    public string Herbs { get; set; }

    public override void GetMyType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Biological");
    }
}
```

I am really a beginner and I have no idea about what I should do or change. I have read other answers on the same topic and I did not understand what to do.

Comment: Can you also post your Entity classes: Category, Chemical and Product?  Also, you are trying to add and update "Chemical" though a repository typed for "Product".

Comment: The types of a value in the database is not the same as your class definition.  With Entity there is a EDMX mapping file that is used to map the c# classes to the database fields.  One or more are not matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are creating 3 *new* entities and trying to Add, Update and Delete them. A new entity can be Added, but cannot be Updated or Deleted. Think about it, it is an object that you have just created, and it is not in the database yet. How do you expect to Update/Delete it? To Update or Delete an entity it must be an existing one.

Second, you are using newly created (without any Id) `Address` and `Category` objects to update `myAdress` and `MyCategory` properties. Those two are not primitive properties representing column values like the rest of them, they are related entities with foreign key constraints. If you really want to change/update them, you must set one that is already existing in database with Id. Otherwise, it will violate the foreign key constraint (or, referential integrity constraint), that's exactly is what the first error message is saying.

Try the following, for Update -

```cs
// retrieve an existing address from database
Address newAddress =  new GenericRepository<Address>().GetById(3);

// retrieve an existing category from database
Category newCategory = new GenericRepository<Category>().GetById(5);

// retrieve an existing product from database
Chemical p2 =  new GenericRepository<Product>().GetById(12);

// update/change properties, but don't change the ProductId
p2.DateProd = DateTime.Now;
p2.myAdress = newAddress;
p2.Description = "CHemichal Update Product";
p2.Price = 55;
p2.Name="PHARMA CHEMICH 1 Update";
p2.Quantity = 100;
p2.MyCategory = newCategory;

// now call for update
productRepository.Update(p2);
```

and for Delete -

```cs
// retrieve an existing product from database
Product p3 = productRepository.GetById(11);

// now call for delete
productRepository.Delete(p3);
```